# Send location coordinate to another iPhone

Tags: iphone, networking, maps, communication

I am trying to write an app that communicates with another app. I just want to see the other person on my map. Is this possible ? I can handle all the map details if I can get the coordinates in real time. Any advice on communicating with other iPhones would be great. I donot want to use Apple Push Notification service.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by having some web service running that allows the iphone to get and send information to it.  Look around this site, the question of how to make requests from a service through the iphone has been asked many many times. Specifically look at NSURLRequest/NSURLMutableRequest [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ...hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into Bonjour services for the iphone. If you want one instance of your app to communicate with another instance of the same app on another iphone, then this is probably what you want, unless you want to use gamecenter.

With bonjour services you can advertise a service on the phone while the app is running and have the other iphone connect to that service and send it some data.